# CSS static width side columns, min-max width center content column

Tags: layout, css

I have the following fiddle for people to see http://jsfiddle.net/defaye/DhaHP/4/
The result on full screen: http://jsfiddle.net/defaye/DhaHP/4/embedded/result/

The problem I'm having is that when going past a certain width of resizing the window, the left column departs from the group. I need them to remain touching, with the centre column having a min-width 400 to max-width 800px, the sides width: 200px. The header should be 100% however.

Anyone know how to solve this problem? It is driving me insane.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is another example, compatible with IE6+: http://jsfiddle.net/DhaHP/12/
Result: http://jsfiddle.net/DhaHP/12/embedded/result

Abstract of the changes:

- Changed `#left` and `#right` to be above the `#center` (`#right` before `#left`);
- `min-width` and `max-width` on `#container` to 800px and 1200px respectively;
- No float on `#center`;
- `margin-left` and `margin-right` on `#center` equals the width of each side column;
- `float-left` on `#left` and `float-right` on `#right`;

The only obs on this for IE6 is the min-width and max-width that doesn't work without a little hack or the use of `IE7.js`. On IE7, it works as should be.

Comment: Just change the width restrictions to `#container` instead of `body`: http://jsfiddle.net/DhaHP/7/embedded/result/  If needed, set the max-width for the footer as well.

Comment: What is the purpose of having the the order `#right`, `#left`, `#center` on the divs?

Comment: I tested it, and as long as the `#center` div is last, both `#left` and `#right` appear in their correct positions. I'm guessing it has to do with the margin property, and by not floating `#center` allows the other divs to overlap?

Comment: Yes. This is the default behavior of floated elements. The margin serves to "reserve" the space of the sidebars, preventing elements, border and background of the center to stay behind the floated bars, but are not exactly needed, if this is not a problem.

Answer (score 1):

Here's a working fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/DhaHP/8/ (edit: now works with Chromium)

Modifications made:

- HTML: #left before #center column
- CSS: no relative positioning at all
- **`display: table;`** on parent and `table-cell` on the 3 columns. This will be visually (and only visually) a table. Well, a table layout and not a table structure.
- 200px width on `#left` and `#right`
- **`table-layout: fixed;`** on parent to switch the table algorithm to the one that respect dimensions as told by the author and not those guessed by dimensions of content of cells
- Constrained widths for the parent **`min-width: 800px;`** (400+200+200) and on the grand-parent **`max-width: 1200px;`** (800+200+200) (edit: max-height on #container only worked on Fx, not Chrome). To my surprise, it works as is.

Compatibility: IE8+
You can play with inline-block with IE6/7 if needed (well, `display: inline; zoom: 1;` the IE6/7 equivalent of inline-block for outdated browsers)

Comment: Thank you, hopefully [IE6 compatibility](http://www.ie6countdown.com/) won't be needed soon :)

Comment: You're right, same with Chromium: max-height doesn't seem to work on the div with `display: table`. You'll have to wrap the latter in a parent `div` and apply `max-height` to this one. Updated fiddle for Webkit: http://jsfiddle.net/PhilippeVay/DhaHP/8/